SAP S4/HANA Condition Base KONV-KAWRT is wrongly set
The value in the condition base KONV-KAWRT is divided by 10!
These happened for all conditions even for manually set ones.
And for all pricing procedures and all document types as well.
Really no clue from where that effect is coming, and it looks like an overall setting in the system.
I checked the whole customizing from the pricing procedure but without a result.
I don't think that is caused by a customizing setting.
Could be a user exit or an enhancement but I'm struggling to debug that

Some ABAP programs (mainly in the SD module) may handle currency amount packed fields with a moving decimal point depending on the currency code, i.e. the technical decimal point is ignored. See here.

Problem was Fixed point arrithmetic settings in a program
